# How to get list of all files and their raw contents under the GitHub project folder using the Java?

Tags: java, file, github, github-api

I am trying to read the files and each file's raw contents under the particular folder of the GitHub URL but I am not getting the right response.

Basically, I would like to do something like this:

1. I have a public GitHub project within which I have a folder `folder1`. This `folder1` contains many files either `XML/JSON`.
2. I want to use the link which is pointing towards `folder1`: `https://github.com/comapny/project/tree/master/folder1/tempFolder` and get its content.
3. Under this folder I have many files whose contents I want to read raw data.

As of now, I am able to make requests to single files and their raw data under the folder but unable to read files under the folder and read all files and their content.

Following is the code I have so far:

```
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Read the GitHub files
        final String inputURL = "https://github.com/company/project/tree/master/XML/withData";
        //final String inputURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/company/project/blob/master/XML/withData/myFileName.xml";
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(inputURL));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + statusLine.getStatusCode() + " ---- " + "Response Phrase :  " + statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        System.out.println("Response body: " + responseBody);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GitHub's repository content API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content) to list files in a directory as well as read file contents.

For example, listing the files in the directory called "XML" could look like the following:

`https://api.github.com/repos/company/project/contents/XML/`

The response would be an array of items in the directory. Each item includes the property `type`, which lets you know whether the item is a file or directory, as well as `url`, a link to request that item.

By performing a new request to an item's URL, you can access the contents of a file through its `content` property, or if it is a directory, you can access another array of files inside.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Can I read the projects which do not belong to me but have public access to? Do I need to pass any of my credentials in API while passing the request? I tried some things but did not work so thought of confirming

Comment: Yes, reading repository contents should work on any public repositories without authentication. What's not working with your request?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Actually its working for me. Thanks again :)